# Please help me with Android Camera issue

Tags: android, api, camera

Dear world's android developers.

Please help me with android camera API issue.

I want to take a photo through android camera and set it as ImageButton's image.
     And if there is media store, save image to the special path.

The problem is as following.

It works on some android devices such as ZTE 2.2 ,Samsung Galaxy 2.3.3 and Samsung tablet 4.0.3, etc.

But it doesn't work on some other devices such as 2.3.4 LG Droid.

I mean that captured image is not set to image button.

(2.3.4 LG Droid's detailed device information is :
   Hw version: Rev .1.1,
   Sw version: ms910zbc,
   Build number gingerbread)

This is my code.

```
String mPhotoPath;
ImageButton mPhotoButton;

mPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (storageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            File photoFile = new File(mPhotoPath);
            try {
                if (!photoFile.exists()) {
                    photoFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    photoFile.createNewFile(); 
                    photoFile.setWritable(true, false);
                } 
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        }else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        }
    }
});



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PICTURE: {
            if (data != null) { //ZTE 2.2 device
                try {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    if (extras != null)
                    {
                        fPhoto = extras.getParcelable("data");
                        mPhotoButton.setImageBitmap(fPhoto);
                    }                       
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            else //Samsung 2.3.3 device
            {
                try {
                     FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(mPhotoPath));
                     fPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                     stream.close();
                     mPhotoButton.setImageBitmap(fPhoto);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
       }
    }
}
```

I appreciate all your helps.

Thanks.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Camera extends Activity 
  {
 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
 private String selectedImagePath;
 ImageButton mPhotoButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPhotoButton=(Button)findElementById(R.id.imgbtn1);
    mPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
   }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) 
        { 
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();randomGenerator.nextInt();
            String newimagename=randomGenerator.toString()+".jpg";
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    + File.separator + newimagename);
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //write the bytes in file

            try {
                fo = new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsoluteFile());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                uri=f.getAbsolutePath(); 
                mPhotoButton.setImageResource(uri);
    //this is the url that where you are saved the image
      }



  }
```

Try the above code...